# browser.baseUrl is unexpectedly changed while protractor testing

Tags: angular, protractor, config, base-url

This is an addition to the question [Protractor cannot find selector in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049609/protractor-cannot-find-selector-in-the-page/53053604)
While testing browser.baseUrl is changed from value pointed out in protractor.conf.js to the value related to localhost. It is very strange because there are only 3 entries to browser.baseUrl and all they are read, without any apparent attempts to change them.
The part of conf.:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 45000,
  restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://dev2.int3.mysite.com',
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  params: {
    space: 'DEV2',
    portinUseCase: {
      existingMsisdn: '777777777'
    },
    pushGatewayUrl: 'https://scapp-corp.mysite.com/',
    login: {
      url: 'https://dev2.int3.mysite.com/store',
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    }
  },
```

This issue was described before, for example, here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5705
But a recipe proposed there doesn't work anymore. So is there any reasonable explanation and solution?

Comment: please put as information protractor version and check your code if somewhere browser override the baseUrl

Comment: 1) Protractor version is 5.4.1
---------------
2) I cannot see any browser attempts to re-write baseUrl.